# Is there an equivalent of Sentry error reporting for App Engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I learnt that it is not possible to use Sentry for AppEngine. Is there a way to have the same error aggregation style on AppEngine?

We are using AppEngine with Django.

Comment: You CAN use sentry with appengine, you just need to use synchronous transport (to get around your app running in a single thread). this works fine if a little inefficient, if you want more, you might want to write your own transport that uses task queues, like https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/modules/appengine/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we installed Sentry on Compute Engine and Raven in our App Engine app. We are now able to report App Engine errors on Sentry !